# C++ No matching constructor

Tags: c++

Recently, I've begun studying C++, and this is my first C++ program - but it does not work.

Error message:

> No matching constructor for initialization of "Document".

The IDE I use is Xcode.

```
    class Document {

    private:

    int doc_id;
        int lan_id;
        std::vector<int>::size_type n_total;
        std::vector<int> words;
        std::vector<int> counts;

        inline int doc_type(){return (counts.empty() && !words.empty())? 1:0;};
    public:

        Document(int docId)
        {
            doc_id = docId;
            n_total = 0;
        }
        Document(int docId, int lanId)
        {
            lan_id = lanId;
            doc_id = docId;
            n_total = 0;
        }

        inline void add(int word, int count)
        {
            words.push_back(word);
            counts.push_back(count);
        }
        inline void add(int word) { words.push_back(word);}
        inline int word(int i) { return words[i]; }
        inline int count() { return counts[1];};
        inline std::vector<int>::size_type size() {  return n_total;};
        inline void setSize(std::vector<int>::size_type total){ n_total = total;};
        inline std::vector<int>::size_type  types() { return words.size();}

        ~ Document()
        {
            words.clear();
            counts.clear();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Wherever you're making the object, you have to call an existing constructor.

Comment: your constructor is private.

Comment: How are you creating an instance of document?

Comment: Your first program in any language is required to be "Hello World".

Comment: show us your main function source code?

Comment: are you calling default constructor which you haven't declared or defined?

Comment: Show us your code where you actually instantiate the class.

Comment: Your use of the `inline` keyword is redundant and unnecessary, as function definitions inside a class declaration are automatically `inline`.

Comment: You've edited your question with a second question. Instead, please post it as a new question (and edit it out of this one), as Stackoverflow is not meant to be used in this way.

Comment: @TJD Yes, it should been it. While I prefer try some useful practice to learn a new language.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are trying to instantiate your `Document` class by using default constructor, however, you do not have a default constructor defined in you code.
You only defined two overloaded versions of the constructor in your public section:

```
Document(int docId, int lanId)
```

and

```
Document(int docId)
```

If you instantiate your object as follows

```
Document d;
```

it will give you compile error since compiler cannot find a default constructor to finish the creation of the object. Meanwhile, you have defined your own constructors, so compiler will not generate a default constructor for you.

Besides, you have several places that put redundant semicolons  there, which is error-prone and should not be there.

For example:

```
 inline int doc_type(){return (counts.empty() && !words.empty())? 1:0;};
                                                                     //^^^^
 inline int count() { return counts[1];};
 inline std::vector<int>::size_type size() {  return n_total;};
 inline void setSize(std::vector<int>::size_type total){ n_total = total;};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I instantiate the Document object without any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the code you haven't shown us, where you try to create an object of this type. You need to use one of the defined constructors:

```
Document d1(docId); 
Document d2(docId, lanId);
```

My wild guess is that you're trying to default-construct one:

```
Document d;
```

The class doesn't (and probably shouldn't) have a default constructor `Document()`, so this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used a default-contruct.